# How do I recreate this color styling effect in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, overlay

[image: Colour Style]

So I'm working on a project and can't quite get the colour overlay effect like in the above image where the orange lays over the newspaper. Any ideas on how I can recreate this technique myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

It should be simple to do if you build your layers like this.

**top**
White text
Orange layer set to multiply
Levels layer (if needed)
Black and white image
**bottom**

[image]

If levels are needed, just push the contrast and maybe make the black more grey if you want it to appear faded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I will suggest:

1. Above the color image you have add a solid color
2. Choose orange or any other color you like
3. Change the blend mode to "Color"
4. Above the new color layer add your text layer and use white for text color

It should give you the same result. You can experiment by double-clicking on the solid color layer and changing the color to other hue values and you will see the result on your image as you change the picked color.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, well i suggest try this

1. Add Hue,saturation adjustment layer

   - set Saturation to -100
   - this will desaturate your image & turns into B/W
2. Add gradient map adjustment layer

   - select the required tints

if you are new to gradient maps it will be better if you search for some tutorials on it, i hope this helps reply back if it works